# Examples of group families with solvable uniform word problem

Tags: gr.group-theory, geometric-group-theory, combinatorial-group-theory, fuchsian-groups, word-problem

I would like to know of any examples of families of groups that are known (or conjectured) to have a solvable uniform word problem, i.e. an algorithm that given a presentation $P$ of a group in the family, and a word $W$ in the generators of $P$, decides whether $W$ represents the identity of the group defined by $P$.

In particular, I'm curious about finitely generated Fuchsian groups.

Comment: Families of groups or families of group presentations? The nuance can be delicate (having in mind that there's no algorithm determining when finite presentation defines a trivial group).

Comment: I'm interested in any examples independently of which of the two definitions is used.

Comment: The word problem is uniformly solvable in finitely generated Fuchsian groups (for any family of presentations). They’re all virtually free or virtually surface groups, which makes it very easy.

Comment: The difference between solvabilty and uniform solvabilty of the word problem is typically one of difficulty. For example hyperbolic groups have uniformly solvable word problem but that is very difficult whereas the word problem is solvable in linear time.

Comment: @Agelos - I think that YCor's is (sort of) suggesting is that you should decide what you mean, and then ask your question as narrowly as you can.  This will get better answers...

Comment: One relator groups have a uniform word problem via Magnus's approach

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Derek Holt is the expert here - I hope he will correct me where I err.

---

There are many such families.  Here are a few ones that spring to mind (or were mentioned in the comments above), in no particular order.

1. fuchsian groups
2. fundamental groups of three-manifolds
3. hyperbolic groups
4. automatic groups
5. one-relator groups
6. residually finite groups

---

Here is the general idea for families (1) to (5).  Suppose that $\mathcal{F}$ is a family of (finitely presentable) groups.  Suppose also that $\mathcal{F}$ comes with a solution to the "certification problem".  That is, there is an algorithm that, given a finite presentation $P$ of a group $G \in \mathcal{F}$, produces a (useful!) proof that $G$ lies in $\mathcal{F}$.  We then use this proof to solve the word problem for $P$.

---

Here is an example in more detail.  Suppose that $\mathcal{F_3}$ is the family of fundamental groups of closed, connected three-manifolds.  Given a presentation $P$ (promised to be of a group in $\mathcal{F_3}$), our algorithm returns

1. a one-vertex triangulation $T$ of a three-manifold $M$ and
2. a sequence of Tietze moves connecting $P$ to the triangulated presentation of $\pi_1(M)$ coming from $T$.

The existence of an algorithm for the word problem for $\pi_1(M)$ (and thus $P$) follows from geometrisation.

---

Another example may be integer linear groups, but there is a subtle point.  We need an algorithm that, given a finite collection of invertible integer matrices, produces a finite presentation of the group they generate.  Does such an algorithm exist?

**EDIT:** As pointed out by HJRW (in the comments) there is no such algorithm.  This is [proven](https://arxiv.org/abs/1003.5117v2) by Bridson and Wilton.

Comment: Are you sure "hyperbolic groups" is such a family? Do you really have an algorithm which inputs a finite presentation and which, if the presented group is hyperbolic, provides you some $\delta$ such that the group is $\delta$-hyperbolic?

Comment: My plan for a (promised) hyperbolic group $G$, given $P$, was to list all presentations of $G$ reachable from $P$, and wait for a Dehn presentation to appear.  I thought that Dehn presentations are recognisable...  However, a quick Google search turns up only one preprint (by Arzhantseva) who requires a side condition.  So perhaps recognising Dehn presentations is open?

Comment: Perhaps it is safer to replace the family $\mathcal{F}_\mathrm{Hyp}$ of hyperbolic groups by the family $\mathcal{F}_{\delta}$ of $\delta$-hyperbolic groups.

Comment: @YCor Yes, there is an algorithm to do that. David and Epstein wrote a paper "Computation in word-hyperbolic groups" to compute $\delta$. But the easiest and most practical way to solve the owrd problem is to compute an automatic structure and use that. The problem with all of these methods is that you cannot predict how long they will take as a function of the length of the presentation, because if you could then you could decide whether an aritrary presentation defined a hyperbolic group

Comment: ... But if somehow you know that the presentation defines a hyperbolic group, then the method will work.

Comment: @SamNead : could you explain how given a presentation $P$ of a group in $F_3$ you obtain a triangulation of a three-manifold? And could you write a few more words on how you get an algorithm from geometrisation?

Comment: @Agelos - For your first question: we run three procedures at the same time.  The first produces, one at a time, all presentations of $G = \langle P \rangle$.  The second  lists, one at a time, all finite (one-vertex) three-dimensional triangulations, and writes down the resulting presentation.  The third watches the two lists, and checks if they ever intersect.

Comment: For your second question I recommend the paper "Decision problems for three-manifolds and their fundamental groups" by Aschenbrenner, Friedl, and Wilton, available here: https://arxiv.org/abs/1405.6274.  They state the solution to the uniform word problem as Theorem 4.1.

Comment: The aforementioned paper of Aschenbrenner, Friedl, and Wilton gives an elementary 10-line proof (Lemma 4.3.) of the following statement: The Word Problem is uniformly solvable in the class of finitely presented residually finite groups. I like this as an answer to my original question.

Comment: The answer to your final question is “no” — there is no algorithm that computes a presentation for a finitely presented group given by matrices. Bridson and I preobwd this in https://arxiv.org/abs/1003.5117v2 .

Comment: Also, I want to push back slightly against the implication that there is a “general idea” that works for all of your first 5 families. The solution for one-relator groups is completely different to the solutions for the first 4.

Comment: @HJRW - I meant "Given a finite presentation of a one-relator group, we can do brute force search to find a one-relator presentation, and then do..." In each of the first five, we have to improve the presentation (or find the automatic structure, or...) before we can start to solve the word problem.

Comment: I tried to say that in the paragraph immediately below the list.  How should I clarify?

Comment: @SamNead: Well, as Derek points out, this is not actually how you uniformly solve the word problem in hyperbolic groups either. But I think the point you are making addresses YCor's comment on the original question about the difference between families of groups and families of presentations. So you perhaps want to say: ... (cont'd)

Comment: "If there is a r.e. family of presentations $P$, containing at least one from each group in your family $F$, and such that the word problem is uniformly solvable in $P$, then the word problem is uniformly solvable in $F$, since a naive search using Tietze moves will always find a presentation in $P$." Or something.